# How to extract and save an XML child node in R?

Tags: r, xml, dataframe, rstudio

I would like to extract only the child node "body" from a given XML file and then save it again as an XML file. How can I achieve this?
The XML file looks like this:

```
<books>
  <book date="2019-01-04" xml:lang="de">
    <title>...</title>
    <body>...</body>
    <copyright>...</copyright>
    <categories>
      <category>
        <topic d="0">...</topic>
        <topic d="1" label="True">...</topic>
      </category>
    </categories>
    <authors>...</authors>
    <published>...</published>
    <isbn>...</isbn>
    <url>...</url>
  </book>
...
</books>
```

I already tried the function saveXML but I don't know how I can choose only one node.

I expect a XML file like this:

```
<books>
  <book date="2019-01-04" xml:lang="de">
    <body>...</body>
  </book>
...
</books>
```